# Why does plotly not recognise the color palette?

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I have a really simple graph to plot, for which I want to use the color palettes of library(RColorBrewer).

When using the sample code:

```
plot_ly(iris, x = ~Petal.Length, y = ~Petal.Width,  type="scatter", mode = "markers",color = ~Species , 
    marker=list( size=20 , opacity=0.5)  )
```

everything works fine. However, when using my data:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~z, y = ~pagerank_persistence,  type="scatter", mode = "markers",color = ~Species,marker=list( size=20 , opacity=0.5)  )
```

R just says: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Objekt 'Species' nicht gefunden (translated: object "species" not found.

Data looks as follows, where z is a date-code.

```
head(data)
  z degree_in_persistence pagerank_persistence tradeprofit_persistence pfprofit_persistence
2 15371                   0.8                 0.70                    0.00                          0.05
3 15400                   0.8                 0.80                    0.15                 0.05
4 15431                   0.8                 0.85                    0.30                 0.00
5 15461                   0.7                 0.70                    0.30                 0.00
6 15492                   0.8                 0.80                    0.00                 0.00
7 15522                   0.8                 0.90                    0.00                 0.00
```

> 

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What `sample code` are you using?

Comment: http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/121-manage-colors-with-plotly/

Comment: You've got `colour=~Species` in your code, but no `Species` in your data. So `Species not found` makes sense. `Species` is a column in the `iris` data. How do you want your plot coloured?

Comment: Thanks - that did solve the problem, obviously!